# Using iw to decrease the txpower of a wireless nic

Tags: wireless-networking, network-adapter

Any search on the internet reveals only how to increase your tx power, and only by changing your region. What I want to do is programmatically decrease (and increase) the tx power of my card but using any version/combination of the below from the iw documentation (http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/iw#Setting_TX_power):

iw dev  set txpower {auto|fixed|limit} {tx power in mBm}

-or-

iw phy  set txpower {auto|fixed|limit} {tx power in mBm}

doesn't work - there's no error after executing any combination of the above but the tx-power remains the same. I would like to be able to incrementally decrease my tx-power until I can no longer reach a remote device.

I am using iw 3.2 and a alfa usb card but don't want to upgrade iw if this 'issue' is persistent across iw rather if it relates not to iw but my card. My integrated card (Intel Centrino) does change when using the 'phy' version.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com/phpBB/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=6230 so it appears to be something with the rt2800usb driver and kernel 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Some cards don't support netlink interface to kernel which iw uses. Try using iwconfig(iwconfig ifname txpower pwr) which uses ioctl interface to kernel.

Comment: Thanks, tried both but neither worked.